# I'm getting error Call to undefined function

Tags: php, undefined

Hi I'm new to php and testing some of the codes I'm getting an error of undefined function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
 <input type="text" placeholder="type your full name" name="fullname">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
 $getName = "" ;
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $getName = "hello ".test_input($_POST['fullname']);  //Fatal error: Call to undefined function test_input() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ctPHP.php on line 15
   
  function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
 } 
 echo $getName;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I was wondering how to solve this problem , I want to echo out the typed name in the text field , how to solve this one thanks

Comment: What error do you get? Put it above code with `>` before it to highlight please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you need to echo after function created.

First create function `test_input()` then use it after declaration/defination.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="type your full name" name="fullname">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $getName = "" ;
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         function test_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
     }
        $getName = "hello ".test_input($_POST['fullname']);  //Fatal error: Call to undefined function test_input() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ctPHP.php on line 15


    } 
    echo $getName;
?>

</body>
</html>
```